# InetAddress gethostname returning ipAddres on android

Tags: android, inetaddress

I'm building an app on android but I have a problem with this

```
InetAddress.getByName(ipAddres).getHostName() return ip Addres
```

Java

```
InetAddress.getByName(IpAddres).getHostName() return hostname
```

so why on android the same code gives the ip address and not the hostname, I need the hostname

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot get hostname from getHostName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899288/cannot-get-hostname-from-gethostname)

Answer (score 0):

check your DNS server, had a similar issue. I installed and configured dnsmasq and was able to get the hostnames from ip addresses

Comment: is the same code the first on runs on a pc the second on android emulator, also tried on real device same result, I dont have a dns server I,m testing on lan computers maybe is the cable modem or something like that?