# Why is Java's InetAddress getHostName() not giving me the host's name?

Tags: java, android, networking, host, inetaddress

I'm trying to get the device's name using its local IP address on the network. Is this how I'm supposed to do it? ex) Arnold-PC, andoid-nnnnnnnnnn

```
String name = InetAddress.getByName(ip).getHostName();
System.out.println(name);
```

The above should give me the host's name... but instead gives me the local IP address. - 192.168.2.101

as per the documentation...

**public String getHostName ()**

> Returns the host name corresponding to this IP address. This may or
>   may not be a fully-qualified name. If the IP address could not be
>   resolved, the numeric representation is returned instead

Why is it not able to find the host's name?

I don't know much about computer networking... so please excuse my ignorance. :P

Comment: is `nslookup` from the commandline able to determine the name ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot get hostname from getHostName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899288/cannot-get-hostname-from-gethostname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check in the command prompt whether you can able to resolve the ip address using nsloookup

if you can't, then your DNS broken

I would like to quote the few lines from java documentation here

> getCanonicalHostName() Gets the fully qualified domain name for this
>   IP address. Best effort method, meaning we may not be able to return
>   the FQDN depending on the underlying system configuration.

one more trick is to edit host file to get output (not recommended)

Have a look in this answer too

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1899377/2134604)

Comment: I've looked into nslookup and tried "nslookup launchmodem.com" as this is the domain I get from ipconfig. Is that what you meant? If my DNS is broken, is there another way to grab a hosts name? Is it possible to ask the router for the DHCP table?

Comment: If my DNS is broken, is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Try flushing the DNS cache, from a cmd prompt

Comment: "ipconfig /flushdns" same result. I wonder if there would be a way to get JNetPCap on android... surely we could use JNetPCap to find the hostname of devices on a network?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

> If this InetAddress was created with a host name, this host name will be remembered and returned; otherwise, a reverse name lookup will be performed and the result will be returned based on the system configured name lookup service. If a lookup of the name service is required, call getCanonicalHostName.

It seems like plain `getHostName()` won't look up the name if it can't reach out to a DNS server. The DNS server is what will give a name to the host IP address, just like a phone book. Give `getCanonicalHostName()` a try.

Comment: getCanonicalHostName() returns the same result